# Parallelize function taking external pointers (XPtr)

Tags: r, rcpp, rparallel

This question is neither a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37167479) nor of 
[this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6074310), which were about functions returning external pointers.

Here's the issue. The Rcpp code hereafter defines two functions, one which creates an XPtr, and another one which can work on the XPtr.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

//[[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP f(int n) {
  std::vector<int> * v = new std::vector<int>;

  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    v->push_back(i);

  XPtr< std::vector<int> > p(v, true);
  return p;
}

//[[Rcpp::export]]
int g(XPtr< std::vector<int> > p, int i) {
  return (*p)[i];
```

And it works fine:

```
> x <- f(100)
> g(x, 45)
[1] 45
```

Let's try to parallelize calls to `g`. This works:

```
require(parallel)
test1 <- function(a) {
  cl <- makeForkCluster(nnodes=2)
  r <- parLapply(cl, 1:5, function(i) g(a,i) )
  stopCluster(cl)
  return(r)
}
```

Expected behaviour:

```
> unlist( test1(x) )
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

But this doesn't work:

```
test2 <- function(a) {
  cl <- makeForkCluster(nnodes=2)

  p <- g(a, 0)
  r <- parLapply(cl, 1:5, function(i) g(a,i) )
  stopCluster(cl)
  return(r)
}
```

Unexpected behaviour:

```
> test2(x)
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
  2 nodes produced errors; first error: external pointer is not valid
```

The problem seems to arise from the fact that the external pointer is used once in the function before calling the slaves in the cluster. What explains this behavior, and is there a workaround? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the beginning of your function, `a` is a promise, i.e. something that says evaluate a certain expression in a certain environment. When you access the variable, the expression is evaluated, so now `a` is an pointer, and that pointer is specific to the particular R instance. You can look at this using `pryr::promise_info`:

```
test2 <- function(a) {
  cl <- makeForkCluster(nnodes = 2)
  print(pryr::promise_info(a))
  p <- g(a, 0)
  print(pryr::promise_info(a))
  stopCluster(cl)
  return(r)
}
```

Output:

```
$code
x

$env
<environment: R_GlobalEnv>

$evaled
[1] FALSE

$value
NULL

$code
x

$env
NULL

$evaled
[1] TRUE

$value
<pointer: 0x565295e3a410>
```

One way around is to use `eval(substitute(a))`:

```
test2 <- function(a) {
  cl <- makeForkCluster(nnodes = 2)
  print(pryr::promise_info(a))
  p <- g(eval(substitute(a)), 0)
  print(pryr::promise_info(a))
  r <- parLapply(cl, 1:5, function(i) g(a,i) )
  stopCluster(cl)
  return(r)
}
```

I am sure there are better ways. Non-standard evaluation is still a bit foreign to me ...

Comment: Great answer, thanks!! I didn't know `pryr::promise_info` which will certainly prove useful in other situations (I have other problems of the same nature with nested functions calls...). Before asking the question I did try a few things like `get(deparse(substitute(a)))` but I didn't thought to `eval`...

Comment: please have a look on this new question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54764144/