# R non-standard evaluation : get promise value while leaving it unevaluated [or: keep external pointer valid...]

Tags: r, rcpp, non-standard-evaluation, rparallel

This a follow-up to [Parallelize function taking external pointers (XPtr)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54535966)

I won't reproduce the Cpp code here to make things shorter. The problem was to that once a parameter of a function is evaluated, it is defined in the function's environment and, in the case of an external pointer, is no longer available in a fork cluster.

So while this function worked:

```
require(parallel)
test1 <- function(a) {
  cl <- makeForkCluster(nnodes=2)
  r <- parLapply(cl, 1:5, function(i) g(a,i) )
  stopCluster(cl)
  unlist(r)
}
```

This function didn't:

```
test2 <- function(a) {
  cl <- makeForkCluster(nnodes=2)
  p <- g(a, 0)
  r <- parLapply(cl, 1:5, function(i) g(a,i) )
  stopCluster(cl)
  unlist(r)
}
```

As pointed out by Ralf Stubner, this came from the fact that the call `g(a, 0)` forced the evaluation of the promise `a`. He suggested the following work around (here with two debug prints to understand how it works):

```
test3 <- function(a) {
  cl <- makeForkCluster(nnodes = 2)
    print(pryr::promise_info(a))
  b <- eval(substitute(a))
  p <- g(b, 0)
    print(pryr::promise_info(a))
  r <- parLapply(cl, 1:5, function(i) g(a,i) )
  stopCluster(cl)
  unlist(r)
}
```

This allowed to access to whatever was in `a`, but `a` was still an unevaluated promise. But this doesn't work when `test3` is called from another function!

```
test4 <- function(b) test1(b)
test5 <- function(b) test3(b)
```

While `test4` works well (the recursive promise evaluation seems to give a valid pointer),  the workaround in `test3` no longer works when called from `test5`.

The debugging prints show that despite the `eval(substitute(a))` trick, the promise is evaluated. My understanding is that this tricks forces the evaluation of the promise `b` of `test5` in its environment, thus `a` becomes evaluated too.

Is there another workaround? (I tried to play with `pryr::parent_promise` but even the code from the example in the man page gives strange results).

I have other complex problems of this type. A general way to get the content of a promise without evaluating it, or to pass external pointers to other functions, with a `parLapply` call at the very end, without stumbling constantly on this problem, would be much welcome.

Comment: I have no idea how to solve this. Maybe it is best to rethink your approach to parallelization. We don't know enough about your real use-case to offer any advice on this, though.

Comment: @ralf-stubner I currently have satisfying workarounds. I was just trying to improve them / understand things better. Thank you again for your previous answer and for having a look at this question.

Comment: I am with @Ralf here and mostly shake my head:  _most if not all_ solutions to parallel programming _setup_ issues deal with making _very_ certain  the code to run is on the node.  Putzing around with promises does not strike me as helping here but your mileage may, as they say, vary.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I usually agree that it is a terrible idea to bypass "rules" that are here for code security... However in that case I have a hard time to understand why this rules are here -- and if these are indeed rules or merely undesirable side-effects. As long as the xptr has been created before the fork cluster, it should be valid on all nodes. It *is* valid on all nodes, as proved by the fact that `test1` and `test4` work perfectly well.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I don't get why it is a good thing that `test2` doesn't work; the fact that the workaround in `test3` works well make me think that it might not be a good thing at all.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Of course my understanding is limited. I surely should have asked a question on the mechanisms of external pointers validity check instead -- why and when do they become invalid?

Comment: We have been using parallel computing approaches with R since at least the early 2000s when packages like [snow](https://cran.r-project.org/package=snow) started to make it easy(-ish).  You will find 15 years of discussion of these scoping rules in the various list archives, and numerous tutorials and discussions in many places.  I invite you to study those carefully, or just trust current best-of-breed approaches as _e.g._ in the [future](https://cran.r-project.org/package=future) package.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dirk, I'll try to take the time to have a look!

Comment: This is an interesting question from the perspective of how R works. But I suspect you would have to dig very deep to determine the exact reasons. Also note that `mclapply` works.